# Is it possible to obtain a human-readable record of all transactions on a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, logging

For example, a log that shows when which value was changed from what to what in which table, row and field?

Comment: @Michael Haren, I do not know at the moment, because I do not administrate it. We just have an issue with one of our programs and databases which is maintained by someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from investigating a particular issue, its NOT recommended to use Transaction log for this purpose. There are many issues one in particular is reading from it when there are concurrent transactions which can cause access violation errors.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/hugo/archive/2009/01/17/it-s-minus-twenty-five-outside-and-i-m-writing-about-transaction-log-files.aspx

As others have pointed out, roll out your own or use Change Data Capture (CDC) or Change Tracking (CT) if you are using SQL Server 2008 & above.

Answer (score 1):

you are free to roll your own.

perhaps build a log table, and add triggers to record relevant transactions.